# Cannot resolve any hosts, do not have IP address (static assignment not working ??)

Tags: ip-address

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2. I have read and tried lots, but there is obviously something wrong in my config somewhere.

It looks like I have an error in my network config, can someone please help me, but pointing out the obvious to me

My aim is

- to have a static IP
- to have a loopback address

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
          address 192.168.1.250
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          gateway 192.168.1.1
```

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(4) generated by resolvconf(8)
#       DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HANE -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Symptoms:

- When I run `ifconfig -a` I do not have IP address
- I cannot see any website

Here is my ifconfig -a output.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet   HWaddr  00:21:78:13:6a:aa
          BROADCAST MULTICAST   MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536 Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3600 (3.6 KB) TX bytes:3600 (3.6 KB)
```

I cannot see  machine on the network
when I run host bbc.co.uk I get

```
;;connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Is your standard gateway aware of the static IP assignment and is it set up to assign this IP address?

Comment: > When I run 'ipconfig -a'
This is not the command to show your ip but:
   ip addr

Comment: yes gateway is allowing 192.168.1.64 -> 192.168.1.253
No I cannot see the machine in the listed machines, BUT that is not a surprise as the ubuntu machine has no IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `auto eth0` above the `iface eth0` line in order to get the network up at boot. Run `sudo service networking restart` after you added the line in order to avoid rebooting.

You need an entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` it you assign you addresses statically. Due to the fact that `/etc/resolv.conf` is managed by the `resolvconf` service, you need to add `nameserver [your nameserver IP, usually on the gateway]` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and apply the changes with `sudo service resolvconf restart`.

Using DHCP is your gateway supports it is a much more comfortable alternative.

Comment: You can also assign static addresses with DHCP.

Comment: Hi I tried this but, cannot complete actions.
I edited /base added
nameserver 192.168.1.1
but when I run sudo service resolvconf reload it says
  reload: Jon is not running:resolvconf
BUT when I run sudo service resolvconf start it says
  start: Job is already running: resolvconf

???

Comment: Try `sudo service resolvconf restart`. If that fails you might have a syntax error in one of the files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/`. Please add them to you post in that case.

Comment: Hi Karl, checking /etc/resolv.conf I now see my gateway as a nameserver. 
also ps show resolvconf running
So it looks like this is working, I just don't have IP address

Comment: I didn't cover that in my answer before, see the first paragraph now.